# Time synchronization at network Level

Tags: network, ntp, 5g

Let suppose we have a scenario where we are getting 5G network and its phase and time synchronization for the radio interface is PTP(precision time protocol). Using that 5G network I have my local network (which is connected to some 5G dongle via ethernet). In Local network I need to synchronize devices with that 5G network nodes ( 5G base stations etc) In order to get the accurate time measurement values. If I send TCP packet from my device to the some other device on the 5G network ( via 5G dongle-> base station etc) in order to measure the packet reception time, I Definity need to have a clock synchronization on bother devices. So my question is If I synchronize the client and server with NTP and the 5G network (dongle, BS, etc) uses PTP for phase and time synchronization for the radio interface ( I know the radio level time synchronization is different than the application level). Does the client and server clock synchronize?

If there is any confusion in understanding let me know. Thank you!

Comment: *If I synchronize the client and server with NTP and the 5G network* - you can use the 5G link as an additional time source (depending on the client, even with NTP in combination) but you cannot truly synchronize to both.

Comment: @Zac67, thank you for the reply. I have an idea tell me if it makes sense. If all the 5G devices are time synchronized using PTP except only the laptop which I connect with ethernet with the 5G dongle. Now as "PTP typically uses the same epoch as Unix time", I create a python code in my laptop generating Unix time epoch and send it to the network in order to measure the packet reception time at each 5G node. is it make sense? cz after all PTP also uses Unix time system.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time making sense of your question and your comment. If this is about programming some sort of middle code, then that is entirely off topic here, see the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Zac67 in your first comment you said: "you cannot truly synchronize to both" then how I should connect (server and client) to only PTP which 5G network has?

Comment: You can use multiple sources and select between, then synchronize with the best of them but whatever you do, you can only ever synchronize with a single source. How do you suppose would synchronizing to multiple sources look like? They should be very close to each other but not likely synchronized unless by chance.